# Can we modify Map values while iterating in Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<Integer,String>`. I need to be able to first filter out the keys with even numbers then iterate the map values and modify the content of map values. I tried running the code below but the values are not changing. Is it possible in java 8 to modify the values based on some condition while iterating a `Map`?

```
Map<Integer,String> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put(1,"ABC");
    m.put(2,"PQR");
    m.put(3,"XYZ");
    m.put(4,"RST");

Map<Integer,String> m1 =  m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().intValue() %2 == 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        map -> map.getKey(),map -> map.getValue()));
            Map<Integer,String> m3 = m1.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(m2 -> {
                    if(m2.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("PQR")){
                        m2.getValue().replace("PQR","PQR1");
                    } else if(m2.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("RST")) {
                        m2.getValue().replace("RST", "RST1");
                    }
                    return true;
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(m2 -> m2.getKey(), m2 -> m2.getValue()));

System.out.println(m3);
```

The answer I am getting is `{2=PQR, 4=RST}` but my answer should come as `{2=PQR1, 4=RST1}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it all in once, filter for the values you want to change and collect it to a new map like:

```java
Map<Integer, String> collect = m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey() % 2 == 0)
    .peek(e -> {
        if (e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("PQR")) {
            e.setValue("PQR1");
        }
        if (e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("RST")) {
            e.setValue("RST1");
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(collect);
```

Comment: This modifies the original map.

Comment: Don't perform side effects in `peek`, they are not guaranteed to run.

Answer (score 1):

> The answer I am getting is {2=PQR, 4=RST} but my answer should come as {2=PQR1, 4=RST1}

The Strings are immutable, you don't set the new value to the entry. You have to to make a new entry and then collect it to the `Map`:

```
.map(m2 -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(m2.getKey(), m2.getValue().replace("PQR","PQR1")))
```

... or using simple `Map::setValue`.

However, there is a much better way. Basically, you want to:

- Filter these entries having a certain `value`.
- Change these values

Stream API is designed rather to work with `Collection`s than `Map`s, however, they are built on the collection anyway. There is a way, a bit clumsy, but is:

```
Map<String, String> helpMap = new HashMap<>();       // the replacement map
helpMap.put("PQR", "PQR1");
helpMap.put("RST", "RST1");

Map<Integer, String> newMap = m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().intValue() %2 == 0) // only qualified keys
    .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
            entry.getKey(),                         // key -> key
            replacementMap.getOrDefault(            // lookup the value in helpMap
                entry.getValue(),                   // ... by the value as key
                entry.getValue())))                 // ... or keep the original value
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(                      // collect back to Map<Integer,String>
            Map.Entry::getKey,                      // ... keys
            Map.Entry::getValue));                  // ... values
```

Notes:

- The solution is based on mapping the entries each to a new `Map.Entry` with modified values, from which it is easy to complete a new `Map` using the right collector.
- If the value for replacement is not found in `helpMap`, then the original value is used - this is up to you. You can either filter out these invalid values using `.filter(entry -> replacementMap.containsKey(entry.getValue()))` before the `.map(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `replace` method: As a String is immutable, this method returns a new string. But the code ignores this returned value.

for a minimal adaptation of your code, create the `m3` map like this:

```
    Map<Integer,String> m3 = m1.entrySet().stream().map(m2 -> {
        if(m2.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("PQR")){
            m2.setValue("PQR1");
        }else if(m2.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("RST")) {
            m2.setValue("RST1");
        }
        return m2;
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(m2 -> m2.getKey(), m2 -> m2.getValue()));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly fine only instead of returning m2 needs to return true

Comment: No because I changed your original `filter`into `map`. I don't think it's a good idea to change the value in the `filter` method.